# How to to print elements from two tables connected with many-to-many relation by using ".Include" method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I do have three classes: **Guest,Room,Service**.
**Guest** and **Service** are connected with **many-to-many relationship**.

I want to write a programm that prints on the console all subscribed **Guests** to certain **Service**

Here is the code for **Guest,Room,Service** Classes and **DbContext class**:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IT3_my_variant
{
   public class Room
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int Capacity { get; set; }

       public ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
       public Room()
       {

           Guests = new List<Guest>();
       }

       public override string ToString() => this.Id.ToString();
   }

   public class Guest
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }

       public int? RoomId { get; set; }
       public Room Room { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }

   }

   public class Service
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string ServiceName { get; set; }
       public int price { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
   }

       public class HotelContext : DbContext
       {
           public HotelContext() : base("DbConnection")
           { }
           public DbSet<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
           public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
           public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }


       }
}
```

And here is the code from the **main method**:

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IT3_my_variant
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           using(HotelContext db = new HotelContext())
           {

               // Adding Services
               Service s1 = new Service() { ServiceName = "Breakfast in room" };
               Service s2 = new Service() { ServiceName = "Pool" };
               Service s3 = new Service() { ServiceName = "Massage" };
               db.Services.AddRange(new List<Service> { s1, s2, s3 });

               // Добавление гостей 
               Guest g1 = new Guest() { Name = "Tom", Age = 21 };
               Guest g2 = new Guest() { Name = "Jhon", Age = 19};
               Guest g3 = new Guest() { Name = "Oleg", Age = 23 };
               Guest g4 = new Guest() { Name = "Vanya", Age = 25 };
               db.Guests.AddRange(new List<Guest> { g1,g2,g3,g4});

               s1.Guests = new List<Guest> { g1, g2 };
               s2.Guests = new List<Guest> { g3, g1 };
               g4.Services = new List<Service> { s3 };

               db.SaveChanges();

               foreach (Service s in db.Services.Include(s=>s.Guests))
               {
                   System.Console.WriteLine($"{s.ServiceName}");

                   foreach (Guest g in s.Guests)
                   {
                       System.Console.WriteLine($"\t{g.Name} --- {g.Age}");
                   }
               }

               System.Console.Read();

           }
       }
   }
}
```

**i get next error:**
*error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type*

My question is:
Am i using **.Include** method incorrectly, or my **many-to-many** relation between tables **Guest**<->**Services** is not set up correctly at first place?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you upload your code to github? It would be easier to run it locally

Comment: Yes, here is the link:
https://github.com/miljkovich/IT3_my_variant